# Get consolidated details from arraylist containing multiple employee objects

Tags: java, collections

I have a arraylist of employee objects. Where each employee object having details like name, department, salary. I want to print for each department , what is the total no of employees available for that department and what is the total salary of employees in that department. is there any shortest possible way available by using collection module classes and methods to find out this one..

Comment: You can use API Stream (since Java 8) (filtering etc..) https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/

Comment: dont describe the code, post it instead.... and then add what problem do you have with....

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so. E.g. you can use streams: group all elements by department and then for each department count total salaries.

```
employees.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, HashMap::new,
                 Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())))
         .forEach((department, e) ->
                 System.out.format("Department: %s; employees amount: %d; total salary: %d", department, e.size(), e.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).sum()));
```